# Informatica Data Replication, is it possible to split clob source to multiple varchar targets?

Tags: teradata, data-warehouse, database-replication, informatica, real-time-data

I have a source system (Oracle) that contains columns in CLOB datatype. I have calculated the maximum size for them and it exceeded the target VARCHAR  max size (Teradata)
is it possible for informatica data replication to split CLOB column to multiple VARCHAR columns? How?

My ultimate goal is to use multiple source systems and multiple source tables to load to the same target table, I want this to be fast so which mode is insert only and a record should be in the below format

```
source_sys, source_table, trx_timestamp(6), trx_type, PK, val1[,val2,...]
```

Comment: Why don't you want to store the Oracle CLOB as CLOB in Teradata?

Comment: Use Teradata column definition: "Description_Column CHARACTER LARGE OBJECT", it's by far more efficient than storing in VARCHAR. In this case you don't need to break the CLOB.

Comment: it's needed this way for other purposes in the architecture

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible but usually, the workaround for CLOB in Informatica is to set the column Informatica az varchar(64000). Teradata has a CLOB datatype as well so in the create a statement of the TD table you can set it as CLOB. It goes like that:

Oracle CLOB >> Informatica varchar(64000) >> Teradata CLOB.

I had to do this a few times and it works for me.